# How can I Save Result to distinct variable

Tags: powershell, firewall

This is my code & Result :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $AllowedDisplayName = "CSLite_FireWall_Rule_Name"
$ruleallowedname = ( Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "$AllowedDisplayName" )
$ruleallowedEnabled = $ruleallowedname.Enabled
$Profileallowedname = $ruleallowedname.Profiles

$b[0] = $Profileallowedname

echo $ruleallowedEnabled
Echo $Profileallowedname 
Echo $b[0]
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:6 char:1
+ $b[0] = $Profileallowedname
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

False
True
1
6
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:10 char:1
+ Echo $b[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray


PS C:\Windows\system32> $AllowedDisplayName = "CSLite_FireWall_Rule_Name"
$ruleallowedname = ( Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "$AllowedDisplayName" )
$ruleallowedEnabled = $ruleallowedname.Enabled
$Profileallowedname = $ruleallowedname.Profiles

echo $ruleallowedEnabled
Echo $Profileallowedname 
False
True
1
6

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

if you see , I just want to 1 and 6 to two different variable
Because I want to check different result

and this is to check Firewall Rule

have two case :
two rule in this PC 
one for Domain but Disable
the other one is Private , Public and rule is Enable

another case :
two rule in this PC 
one for Domain , Enable
the other one is Private , Public and rule is disable

Just want to make Rule have Private , Public and Enable 
Not Domain Disable to failed this check

and if Private , Public is disable
but have Domain , Enable will be failed to Result

*PS 1 : because this two Rule will be set in same time *
*PS 2 : My English is poor , But I want Know How to do this Check  *

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$AllowedDisplayName = "CSLite_FireWall_Rule_Name"
$ruleallowedname = ( Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "$AllowedDisplayName" )
$ruleallowedEnabled = $ruleallowedname.Enabled
$Profileallowedname = $ruleallowedname.Profiles
$b = @("$($ProfileAllowedName)")
Write-Host $RuleAllowedName
Write-Host $ProfileAllowedName
Write-Host $b[0]
```

Here the @() creates an array. To learn more open powershell and run `about_arrays`

Comment: actually... I would like this : 1 $b[0] , 6 $b[1]  
but ... thank you